# Deleting Folders and its sub-folders in Linux Error

Tags: linux

One of my friends creates a sorting shell script in our PC (Ubuntu is the OS ).
But will an fault in this codes, the programs continuously creating subfolders with in a folder.

Here is a sample of the directory:

```
/CC02/D_C01/6001/CC02/D_C02/6001/CC02/D_C04/6001/CC02/D_C04/6001/CC02/D_C04/6001/CC02/D_C05/6001/CC02/D_C05/6001/CC02/D_C05/6001/CC02/D_C01/6002/CC02/D_C04/6002/CC02/D_C04/6002/CC02/D_C04/6002/CC02/D_C05/6002/CC02/D_C05/6002/CC02/D_C05/6002/CC02/D_C01/6003/CC02/D_C02/6003/CC02/D_C04/6003/CC02/D_C04/6003/CC02/D_C04/6003/CC02/D_C05/6003/CC02/D_C05/6003/CC02/D_C05/6003/CC02/D_C01/6004/CC02/D_C02/6004/CC02/D_C04/6004/CC02/D_C04/6004/CC02/D_C04/6004/CC02/D_C05/6004/CC02/D_C05/6004/CC02/D_C05/6004/CC02/D_C01/6005/CC02/D_C04/6005/CC02/D_C04/6005/CC02/D_C04/6005/CC02/D_C05/6005/CC02/D_C05/6005/CC02/D_C05/6005/CC02/D_C01/6006/CC02/D_C02/6006/CC02/D_C04/6006/CC02/D_C04/6006/CC02/D_C04/6006/CC02/D_C05/6006/CC02/D_C05/60
```

I cancelled the script and try to delete the folder starting at the top using the following code:

```
rm -f *
```

But I'm receive the following error:

```
rm: cannot determine if this is an ancestor of the current working directory
```

Comment: You need `rm -rf` not just `rm -f`.

Comment: Which directory were you in when the rm(1) command was issued?  What kind of filesystem is this?  Is the storage local or remote?  If you unmount the filesystem, does '# fsck -f /path/to/device' show any errors?  How  does the script create these directories?  We need more details.